# HLS Offline for Event Playlists

Tags: ios, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am trying Apple's HLS Offline capabilities to try to download and playback locally the video from an [Event Playlist](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-EVENT_PLAYLIST). However, I'm only able to download and play the video offline when it's a [VOD Playlist](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-TNTAG2). **Question** is: Is Offline HLS supported only for VOD Playlists?

Some context about my environment:

1. I'm relying on [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016757-CH11-SW11) to download & play my video.
2. Video plays just fine.
3. The delegate method `URLSession:assetDownloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` is called as soon as the download starts, which is surprising. This is what makes me think it is not supported.
   3.1 Inspecting that URL ^^, it points to a `movpkg` file but nothing can be found on the app container.
4. After a few seconds of download, I call [playOfflineAsset()](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016757-CH11-SW11) but `isPlayableOffline` from the `AVAssetCache` is always `false`. Unless it's a VOD playlist where it is `true`.
5. I'm streaming in a local network. So, if this is a copyright issue and permission rules can be bent for being in a local network, that's something I could do.

**Update**

I overrode `urlSession(URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError: Error?)` from `URLSessionTaskDelegate` and it is called with error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16655), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

Which explains why **3.** from above happens so early. Because the request is actually failing. This probably confirms that HLS Offline doesn't work for Event or Live Playlists. In any case, if someone has some facts to back that up, I'd appreciate if they can be shared.

Answer (score 1):

I reached out to an Apple AVFoundation Engineer who confirmed that Offline HLS is only available for VOD Playlists (as of iOS 11.2).